# Any difference between using this to access the watcher's value and using the argument?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is not particularily important, but I am trying to learn Vue.

Is there any difference between which of these two values is used? They should always be the same, right?

For example:

```
watch: {
    myVar(value) {
        console.log('this.myVar, value, this.myVar === value', this.myVar, value, this.myVar === value)
    }
}
```

Is the inclusion of this argument just for convenience/readability? Or is there some reason one would use one or the other?

Answer (score 3):

`this.myVar` and `value` are the same in this case. The use of `value` is tiny bit more efficient because it doesn't require to access `this` property again, and it's shortened to one-letter variable in minified build. More importantly, it can be named for readability or brevity, and can be complemented with another parameter:

```
myVar(value, oldValue) {
  ...
```

In case a watcher is asynchronous, `value` captures the original value, while `this.myVar` contains the current value, which may be desirable or not depending on a case:

```
async myVar(value, oldValue) {
  ...
  console.log(this.myVar !== value);
```